# Is there a way to capture HTML event attributes with Python?

Tags: python, html

I'm looking to host a server where I can capture and analyze the traffic for a client that tries to inject a XSS script through the HTML event attributes. So far, I've seen some use cases for Scapy but I don't see how this could be used in capturing an HTML event attribute. If anybody could point me in the right direction, I would greatly appreciate it!